# Как в XML понять, что блоки соединены между собой?

Tags: javascript, xml

Есть xml, ее нужно обработать, и понять, какой блок соединен между собой и представить в адекватном виде

```html
<mxGraphModel dx="1434" dy="953" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="826" pageHeight="1169" background="#ffffff">
  <root>
    <mxCell id="0"/>
    <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
    <mxCell id="4" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;html=1;exitX=1;exitY=0.5;entryX=0;entryY=0.5;jettySize=auto;orthogonalLoop=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="2" target="3">
      <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="2" value="A" style="whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="100" y="60" width="120" height="100" as="geometry"/>
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="3" value="B" style="whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="380" y="55" width="110" height="110" as="geometry"/>
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="5" value="C" style="whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="100" y="290" width="120" height="60" as="geometry"/>
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="7" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;html=1;exitX=0;exitY=0.5;entryX=1;entryY=0.633;entryPerimeter=0;jettySize=auto;orthogonalLoop=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="6" target="5">
      <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="6" value="D" style="whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="400" y="300" width="120" height="60" as="geometry"/>
    </mxCell>
  </root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

Все это рисуется на draw.io (как эта xml выглядит на холсте )
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понял атрибуты, source="2" target="3",  это из id 2 в id 3 идет. 
Но как можно все это дело парсить и в тот же JSON преобразовать?

Comment: на вскидку, у вас XML явно задаёт 6 объектов. 4 - прямоугольники, они имеют атрибут `value` и и чего не знают о том, с кем они соединены. 2 - соединительных линии, с атрибутами `source` и `target`, которые знают с кем они соединены. Попробуйте искать такие соединительные линии и из них уже вытягивать информацию а связях между объектами. Ну и приведите пример. что вы понимаете под `представить в адекватном виде`

Comment: как это можно представить например в json, связи

Comment: смотря как вы хотите это потом использовать, вариантов много и все со своими плюсами и минусами. Так что выбор того, как именно будет выглядеть результат после преобразования XML => JSON исключительно за вами. Способ преобразования в принципе тоже. Я не владею в достаточной степени JavaScript чтобы написать пример, но есть минимум 3 варианта: XSLT преобразование, ручной парсинг, какой-нибудь фреймворк умеющий парсить XML и/или формировать JSON

Comment: XSLT преобразование, а есть статьи на эту тему?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: Если приведете пример как должен выглядеть JSON, смогу показать пример XSL-файла для преобразования

Comment: понял, спасибо еще раз) главное сейчас научится парсить такой XML файл